# How to print the minimum and maximum of factor level summary statistics (taking minimum and maximum of medians/proportions)?

Tags: r, summary, summarize

I have data as follows, including 10 products (a, b, c, ...), and their descriptions (other variables).

I need to report how the summary statistics of other variables (median/proportion) range between products (should be printed as a minimum and maximum for each summary statistic value).

**For example:**

Which product has the lowest and which the highest **median price** (need to report only two values, product names do not matter).

Which product has the lowest and highest **proportion of "bad" ratings** (need to report only two values, product names do not matter).

**Is there an easy way to code it? My actual data has 10,000 products and 150 other variables, eyeballing summary tables would kill me.**

**Data**

````
```{r}
data.frame(
product = rep(letters[1:10], each = 2, times = 500),
price = rnorm(1000, 100, 30),
weight = rnorm(1000, 8, 2),
price_category = rep(c("expensive", "cheap"), each = 4, times = 250),
rating = replicate(1,sample(c("good", "bad"),1000,rep=TRUE)))
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can look into `dplyr` package which will make it easy to answer such questions.

1. Which product has the lowest and which the highest median price

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  summarise(median_price = median(price)) %>%
  slice(which.min(median_price), which.max(median_price))

#  product median_price
#  <chr>          <dbl>
#1 f               91.9
#2 e              107.
```

2. Which product has the lowest and highest proportion of "bad" ratings

```
df %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  summarise(prop_of_bad_ratings = mean(rating == 'bad')) %>%
  slice(which.min(prop_of_bad_ratings), which.max(prop_of_bad_ratings))

#  product prop_of_bad_ratings
#  <chr>                 <dbl>
#1 j                      0.44
#2 c                      0.55
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems very promising. Only two more things. Is there a way to summarise all continuous variables at once? Secondly, the "rating" is a categorical variable. How to get the proportion of good vs bad ratings for each product, and then report their min and max?

Comment: By summarise do you mean to take `median` for all ? You can use `df %>% group_by(product) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), median))` for that. For the second question, you can do the same as answer 2 above for `'good'` rating as well and then combine the results if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use data table. The `:=` operator does in-place assignment (in this case creating a new medians column) by grouping on the price column with the `by`
argument. Then you can just find the min and max values. The `.N` operator gets the count of the number of data values.

```
library(data.table)
  
dt <- data.table(data.frame(
    product = rep(letters[1:10], each = 2, times = 500),
    price = rnorm(1000, 100, 30),
    weight = rnorm(1000, 8, 2),
    price_category = rep(c("expensive", "cheap"), each = 4, times = 250),
    rating = replicate(1,sample(c("good", "bad"),1000,rep=TRUE))))
  
dt[, medians := median(price), by=product]

# Highest and lowest median price
dt[c(which.min(medians), which.max(medians)), medians]

# Calculate proportions of each product
dt[, prodcount := .N, by=product]
dt[, percent := 100 * (.N / prodcount), by=.(rating, product)]
bad <- dt[rating == 'bad',]
bad[c(which.min(percent), which.max(percent))]
```